# Как добавить параметр для одной ссылки меню WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на Wordpress, меню выводится стандартным методом `wp_nav_menu()`
Каким образом для одной ссылки могу добавить атрибут `rel="nofollow"`

Answer (score 2):

> Каким образом для одной ссылки могу добавить атрибут rel="nofollow"

Раскрыть настройки экрана, включать "Отношение к ссылке (XFN)" и вписать `rel="nofollow"`.

[image: Отношение к ссылке]

Answer (score 1):

Если это нужно сделать программно, то воспользуйтесь хуком `nav_menu_link_attributes`:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // ID айтема в меню
    $menu_target = 123;

    if ( $item->ID == $menu_target ) {
        $atts['rel'] = 'nofollow';
    }
    return $atts;

}, 10, 3 );
```