# Как добавить атрибут для одного пункта woocommerce_breadcrumbs?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Вопрос в заголовке) У меня есть функция `<?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>`

Как для одного конкретного пункта ( категории) добавить атрибут `rel="nofollow"`

Comment: Точно также https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995576/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e-wordpress

Comment: @SeVlad к сожалению в меню нету категории для товаров. Да и мне требуется лишь для пункта breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать хук `woocommerce_breadcrumb`. Распечатайте, что в него передается и станет понятно как менять:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', function( $breadcrumbs, $args ) {
    print_r( $breadcrumbs );
    print_r( $args );
}, 10, 2 );
```